# SQL join: keep same column name, then refer to it

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm regularly running into the following issue.

```sql
select
  A.command_id             as command_id,
  sum(B.compile_time)      as compile_time,
  sum(B.run_time)          as run_time,
  compile_time + run_time  as total_time
from commands as A
inner join subcommands as B on A.command_id = B.command_id
group by A.command_id
```

This doesn't seem to work because on line 5, the SQL engine seems to think that I'm referring to the columns of table B, and not the columns of the resulting table. Is there a way to fix that? Something like `this.compile_time`?

Of course I can rename the columns of the resulting table, e.g. `total_compile_time` and `total_run_time`. But this situation happens to me enough times that I hate having to be creative about the naming every time. It just makes sense to have the same column names in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use columns name alias in select  because the alias name is  created after the select execution then is not available in select clause.
For avoid error or problem you must repeat the sum function

```
    select
      A.command_id             as command_id,
      sum(B.compile_time)      as compile_time,
      sum(B.run_time)          as run_time,
      sum(B.compile_time) + sum(B.run_time)   as total_time
    from commands as A
    inner join subcommands as B on A.command_id = B.command_id
    group by A.command_id
```

there is a specific sequence for clause evaluation by the db engine  in the db engine sequence evalation the alias resulting after the completion of select clause

Comment: *You can't use columns name alias in select because the alias name is created after the select execution then is not available in select clause.* That is not true. As I mentioned in my question, it works if you use a different name for the columns of the resulting table.

Comment: Same code I wrote, replace `as compile_time` by `as compile_time_sum`, replace `as run_time` by `as run_time_sum`, replace `compile_time + run_time` by `compile_time_sum + run_time_sum`.